# DPY-3015: password verifier type 0x939 is not supported by python-oracledb in thin mode

Tags: python, python-oracledb

I am trying to connect python and oracle db but I cannot downolad any clients as there is no internet connection.

I am using oracledb for that but I am getting this error. Any clue about how to solve it without downolading anything ?

Thank you!

Comment: Out of interest, if don't have internet, how did you install python-oracledb?

Comment: It was installed by the IT department and then it was disabled for security issues....

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that on the server you have the database setting called `sec_case_sensitive_logon` which, when set to the value FALSE and combined with the sqlnet.ora setting `sqlnet.allowed_logon_version_server=10` disables the use of the 11g and 12c verifiers -- which are the only ones that the thin driver supports.

You can see that on this python-oracledb issue [raised earler](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues/26#issuecomment-1189127448).

You will have to disable the case insensitive logon or use the thick driver (which requires downloading the client libraries).

Answer (score 1):

- If you’re connecting to Oracle Database 11gR2 or earlier, then use  python-oracledb Thick mode, or upgrade the DB.
- For later DBs:

  - make sure the database initialization parameter `sec_case_sensitive_logon` is not FALSE.  In SQL*Plus as SYSDBA, run `show parameter sec_case_sensitive_logon` to check the value.
    Note `sec_case_sensitive_logon` has been removed in DB 21c see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nfcon/security-solutions.html#GUID-FAF4C7A6-A2CD-4B9B-9A64-3705F693ECF0).
  - Regenerate passwords e.g. run `ALTER USER x IDENTIFIED BY y`, if necessary, see the Oracle documentation [Finding and Resetting User Passwords That Use the 10G Password Version](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-D7B09DFE-F55D-449A-8F8A-174D89936304).

The error is only seen in Thin mode, so [using Thick mode](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#enabling-python-oracledb-thick-mode) is a general solution.

Comment: If you upgraded from an older DB, like 11g, to 19c or higher, you only need to change the password, even to the same one, then it will get the new verifier version and will work with thin mode client

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue. After debugging the connect method, I figured out that the password version is not supporting 11G and 12C

Supported versions in the python library are (messages.pyx and constants.pxi)

```
    TNS_VERIFIER_TYPE_11G_1 = 0xb152
    TNS_VERIFIER_TYPE_11G_2 = 0x1b25
    TNS_VERIFIER_TYPE_12C = 0x4815
```

So, i did this query to find out what are the password versions

```
select username, password_versions FROM dba_users WHERE username IN ('DB_USER_NAME')
```