# Error Airflow, DPY-3015: password verifier type 0x939 is not supported by python-oracledb in thin mode

Tags: oracle, airflow, oracle19c, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I've already install Oracle Provider package for Apache Airflow
and triying to connect to Oracle (version 19c) with this package, And I got this error

**DPY-3015: password verifier type 0x939 is not supported by python-oracledb in thin mode**
[Error Oracle Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5JiI.jpg)

I googled but still not find the solution
I've tried to use extra parameters but not working.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853023/dpy-3015-password-verifier-type-0x939-is-not-supported-by-python-oracledb-in-th) question?

Answer (score 0):

- If you’re connecting to Oracle Database 11gR2 or earlier, then use [python-oracledb Thick mode](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#enabling-python-oracledb-thick-mode), or upgrade the DB.
- For later DBs:

  - Make sure the database initialization parameter `sec_case_sensitive_logon` is not FALSE.  In SQL*Plus as SYSDBA, run `show parameter sec_case_sensitive_logon` to check the value.
    Note `sec_case_sensitive_logon` has been [removed in DB 21c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nfcon/security-solutions.html#GUID-FAF4C7A6-A2CD-4B9B-9A64-3705F693ECF0).
  - Regenerate passwords e.g. run `ALTER USER x IDENTIFIED BY y`, if necessary